# Relation between diagonal and off-diagonal entries of Hermitian Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

I am started doing a project in Quantum Chemistry and stumbled upon a problem which I can not seem to find the answer to.

As the title suggests, I am looking for a relation between the diagonal and off-diagonal entries of a Hermitian Operator i.e. a Hamiltonian. In literature I could not find any relation between the two. We can diagonalize a Hermitian operator as $H = U^{\dagger}\Lambda U$ where $U$ is some unitary operator and $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $H$. Every entry can be written as:
$$
H_{ij} = U^{\dagger}_{ik}\Lambda_{kl}U_{kj} = \lambda_k U^{\dagger}_{ik}U_{kj}
$$
Now I would like to find some relation between when $(i=j)$ and $(i \neq j)$ for $H_{ij}$. But I can not seem to figure it out. I tried to find some relation by relating it to the eigenvalues:
$$
\Lambda_{ij} = U_{ik}H_{kl}U^{\dagger}_{lj}=
\begin{cases} 
      \lambda_i & i=j \\
      0 & i\neq j 
   \end{cases}
$$
But don't know how to continue from here. Is there some relation between the diagonal elements and off-diagonal elements?

Comment: What do you mean with 'relation' exactly?

Comment: Whether there is some way to write H_{ii} = c_j*H_{ij}, I think?

Answer (score 4):

No. The condition for a matrix to be Hermitian is that the diagonal elements are real and the off-diagonal elements respect $H_{ij} = H^*_{ji}$, so the condition doesn't impose any restrictions on how diagonal and off-diagonal elements relate to each other.

Any relation you find between these elements will be a particular property of the matrix, and not determined by any more general property of Hermitian matrices.

As an example, notice that any Hermitian $2 \times 2$ matrix can be written as
$$H = \alpha \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} + \beta \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} + \gamma \begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ i & 0\end{pmatrix} + \delta \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$ are arbitrary real numbers. Notice how you are completely free to choose the diagonal elements (as long as they are real) in an independent manner of how you choose the off-diagonal elements.

Comment: I agree. There's no necessary condition between diagonal and off-diagonal elements. Maybe this relation follows from another imposition say, det=1, unitarity, or something along those lines»